# How do I display contents from phpmyadmin to my php page in a Table format?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, database-connection

This is my code, the connection is performed in dbConnect.php (which functions correctly), could you guy point me in the right direction. The php code to display the information from my database is in the body, I've seen others use sqli but I seem to get an error because my db connection is in the dbConnect.php. I'm just a little confused on how I could do this without inserting the database connection code in this page. Thanks in advance...

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbConnect.php';
$msgDia="";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/newCss.css">
</head>
<body>
                        <!--Body Container-->
<div class="flex-container">

                        <!--Header Container-->
<header> <a href="tpaHomepage.php"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"></a> 
<div class="title">
  <h1><b><i>Enabling cloud storage auditing with geolocation restrictions on an efficient key update</i></b></h1>
</div>
<ul><center>
  <li><a href="tpaHomepage.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="activateusertpa.php">Activate Users</a></li>
  <li><a href="auditfiles.php">Audit files</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </center>
</ul></header>


                        <!--Login Container-->
<div class="loginForm">
<h2>Users Table</h2>
<p>The users who have recently registered to the system has been presented here for the TPA to enable the clients to access website.</p>

<?php

if ($_SESSION['tpaSession']!="") {
    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM usertbl");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();
    $count=$query->num_rows;
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";
        while($row = $query) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["userid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
} else {
    header("Location: tpaLogin.php");
}
?>

<br>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using mysqli, then your DB connect should show something like:

```
$DBcon = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

For your query/fetch:

```
$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM usertbl");

if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   echo"
   <table><tr>
       <th>ID</th> 
       <th>Firstname</th>
       <th>Lastname</th>
   </tr>
   ";

   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>$row[userid]</td><td>$row[firstname] $row[lastname]</td></tr>
     ";
     }
   echo "</table>";
   } 
else {
  echo "0 results";
  header("Location: tpaLogin.php");
}
```

Comment: $DBcon = new MySQLi("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

Comment: This is what mine looks like

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /home4/wazire24/public_html/wazProject/finalDesign/activateusertpa.php on line 45

Comment: See answer above for some amendments (suggested)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code to the following and it worked perfectly well, thanks for the guide -NiallFH

```
    <?php

if ($_SESSION['tpaSession']!="") {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usertbl";
$result = mysqli_query($DBcon,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
$count=$sql->num_rows;

if ($sql) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["userid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";

}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
}
else {
header("Location: tpaLogin.php");
}
?>
```